# Scale Y axis of Altair chart to interactive legend selection

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

I've copied the interactive legend code from here:
https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/interactive_legend.html

The difference is that my data has different orders of magnitude for the different series, so it would be nice if, when we select a set of series (shift click), we zoom the graph so that it fills the window. Is this possible in Altair?

Current base:

```
base = (
        alt.Chart(source)
        .mark_line(point=alt.OverlayMarkDef(color="red"))
        .encode(
            x=alt.X("date:T", axis=alt.Axis(format='%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M')),
            y="value:Q",
            color="datatype:N",
            opacity=alt.condition(selection, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.2))
        ).add_selection(selection)
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by using your `selection` to filter the data passed to the plot via `transform_filter`.

One this to keep in mind is that we have to pass a custom `scale` otherwise the filtered data will only show legends for the selected field which leads us to a deadlock.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.unemployment_across_industries.url

selection = alt.selection_multi(fields=['series'], bind='legend')
# custom color scale otherwise, non-selected legends will disappear
custom_scale = alt.Scale(domain=pd.read_json(source).series.unique().tolist())
alt.Chart(source).mark_area().encode(
    alt.X('yearmonth(date):T', axis=alt.Axis(domain=False, format='%Y', tickSize=0)),
    alt.Y('sum(count):Q', stack='center', axis=None),
    alt.Color('series:N', scale=custom_scale),
    opacity=alt.condition(selection, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.2))
).add_selection(
    selection
).transform_filter( # get only those selected series
    selection
)
```

[image]

Comment: How do I change this if my source is a DataFrame? Specifically the custom_scale line

Comment: The `pd.read_json(source)` here is basically a pandas dataframe and we are passing the list of unique values in the `series` column. Suppose you have a dataframe `df` and you are plotting different colored areas for a column `target_column`, all you need to pass to as domain argument is `df.target_column.unique()`

Comment: That worked for me, my column was datatype. I have a small bug which is that when I select the smaller magnitude series, the title gets pushed up out of frame, I'm wondering if that happens to you too or if this is a problem with Streamlit, the app I'm using to display the altair chart.

Comment: I checked it on streamlit using `st.write` and `st.altair_chart`. Both didn't affect the position of the title for me. You can try changing the `baseline` [option](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/title.html#params) of `title` properties.

Comment: Ended up just increasing the height property, which is a pretty obvious fix in retrospect. Thanks for your help @LazyClown